# Stop LXDE from automatically starting in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

### Setup

Ubuntu 11.10 Server

LXDE

### Question

After installing lxde, my box runs it on startup. How do I prevent this without uninstalling.

Answer (score 1):

You could always rename the start file:

```
mv /etc/init/lxdm.conf /etc/init/lxdm.conf.nostart
```

Comment: This works, but then you can't start lxde on demand

Answer (score 1):

Although [this site specifically deals with GDM](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/prevent-xorg-from-starting-in-linux/) (Gnome Desktop Manager), you can apply this to LXDE as well.  Basically, you'll want to stop X from running, ala:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f gdm remove
```

Replacing `gdm` with whichever login manager you chose.

---

You could also try installing `lightdm` (the regular login manager for the desktop version of Ubuntu), and then opening up `/etc/defaults/grub` and adding `text` to the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

...resulting in:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash text"
```

Then, run `sudo update-grub` and restart.

Comment: the pesky devil survived this too

Comment: tried `sudo update-rc.d -f lxdm remove` for the record

Comment: I amended my answer to force it into text mode by installing `lightdm`, and having `grub` communicate with it.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo service lxdm stop` should disable it.  (Technically it's not starting "LXDE", it is starting a display manager; LXDE is one of several desktops that a user could choose to run when logging in.)

Comment: I get `lightdm: unrecognized service` with this

Comment: Sorry, wrong service; you really need to combine our answers.  Fixing...

Comment: This works once lxdm is already started, but it doesn't disable auto start